# Bent chainlink gate

Tags: fence, metal, gates

I had a tree fall on my chainlink gate and I'm looking for a smart way to fix it without replacing the whole gate. The hinges on the gate still work but as you can see in the picture there is a huge hole that is letting wildlife through. I feel like I should be able to bend the metal back somehow but I haven't found a method that works yet. How can I fix this gate?

[image: chainlink gate]

Comment: I guess this homeowner's solution wouldn't work for you: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/805611874162180167/1087476940161683616/image.png

Answer (score 1):

First way is to use a come along/winch or a tractor with a chain to pull the top of the gate back.  Will take quite a bit of force, so will need a tree or a good size tractor as an anchor/pulling point.

Second way is to cut some of the deep V out and bend the pipes back.  The section of the deep V you cut will be replaced with a slightly larger diameter pipe to fit over.  Drill holes for bolts or weld to hold.

Answer (score 1):

A proper repair would be to remove the top tube, or at least the bent part of it, and replace with a new tube. While you are at it, clean up all the welded joints and apply cold galvanizing paint, unless you remove the whole gate frame and take it somewhere for welding followed by hot-dip galvanizing. You can tie the chain link across the opening while you get that done.

You can try to straighten the bent tube (*e.g.* with a jack), but it's gone a bit far to expect that to work, and it will probably break.

Comment: I would start from trying to jack up the bent tube. It might work, or at least close the gap somewhat until a replacement can be arranged.

Comment: Closing the gap is as easy as removing the chainlink from the bent gate frame and wiring it to the gateposts until the frame is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It is welded and that makes it more difficult to repair.

Idea:

Cut in the center of the V bend with single cut. That would free both sides so you can bend them up. Would use heat (torch) to make it more malleable. Use top rail connector to connect where it was cut. Bend the left rail back in shape.

Comment: Will that V need reshaping so a top rail connector will fit?